# Python: For Loop breaks to early - Why?

Tags: python, for-loop, breakpoints, break

I want my Code (see below) to take 5 screenshots of each Breakpoint. But after 3 screenshots from Breakpoint 1280 it starts to take screenshots from the next breakpoint.

What I´m doing wrong or what I´m missing?

```
#!/bin/sh

from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

now = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')
Breakpoint_1280 = 0
Breakpoint_768 = 0
Breakpoint_320 = 0

# Set Breakpoint for different View
Breakpoints = [1280, 768, 320]

for points in Breakpoints:
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(points, 800))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    driver.get('https://www.example.com')
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Taking Screnshoot in different Breakpoints
    if points == 1280:
        for a in Breakpoints:
            Breakpoint_1280 += 1
            print ("Taking %s. Screenshot for Breakpoint 1280" %(Breakpoint_1280))
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Breakpoint_1280_Snap%s_%s.png' %(Breakpoint_1280, now))
            time.sleep(10)
            if Breakpoint_1280 == 5:
                break

    elif points == 768:
        for b in Breakpoints:
            Breakpoint_768 += 1
            print ("Taking %s. Screenshot for Breakpoint 768" %(Breakpoint_768))
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Breakpoint_768_Snap%s_%s.png' %(Breakpoint_768, now))
            time.sleep(10)
            if Breakpoint_768 == 5:
                break

    else:
        for c in Breakpoints:
            Breakpoint_320 += 1
            print ("Taking %s. Screenshot for Breakpoint 320" %(Breakpoint_320))
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Breakpoint_320_Snap%s_%s.png' %(Breakpoint_320, now))
            time.sleep(10)
            if Breakpoint_320 == 5:
                break
    display.stop()
```

Hope someone can help me .. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Because you iterate over Breakpoints, and that only has three elements.

Comment: Are you coming to Python from Java or Matlab? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loops with a range of 5 to accomplish what your doing.

`for a in range(5):
    Do something

for b in range(5):
    Do something

for c in range(5):
    Do something
`

Comment: That´s it !! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loops should be something like this:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    .
    .
```

Comment: Wait, what? `for i in range(0,5)` automatically handles the incrementing of `i`, you do not need to additionally `i+=1`

Comment: Also,`range`'s default start is 0, so you only need `range(5)`

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, you are iterating over `Breakpoints` which only has three elements, hence your three screenshots. You should instead use  `for` loop to create 5 shots.
You could also simplify your code a lot by using the value of `points` in your print statements and filenames:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

now = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')

# Set Breakpoint for different View
Breakpoints = [1280, 768, 320]

for points in Breakpoints:
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(points, 800))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    driver.get('https://www.example.com')
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Taking Screnshoot in different Breakpoints
    for i in range(5):
        print ('Taking {}. Screenshot for Breakpoint {}'.format(i, points))
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Breakpoint_{}_Snap{}_{}.png'.format(points, i, now))
        time.sleep(10)

    display.stop()
```

Note that I have also used the newer [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) method for the string formatting.